# How to bootstrap custom locale resolver to validator in a quarkus rest api application

Tags: hibernate-validator

I've created a custom locale resolver for the purpose of internationalization of quarkus rest application. Since I'm new to quarkus, could you please let me know where should I write the following bootstrap code in the application,

ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
.configure()
.localeResolver(customlocaleresolver)
.locales(Locale.GERMAN, Locale.FRENCH, Locale.ITALIAN)
.defaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
.buildValidatorFactory();
return validatorFactory.getValidator();
Also, how should I make controller class to know that locale has to be resolved before sending the response.Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks
I referred this link for internationalization - https://in.relation.to/2020/01/23/hibernate-validator-6-1-1-released/

Adding the custom locale resolver, getting null for httpheader from resteasycontext.

```
public class ResteasyContextLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {
    @Override
    public Locale resolve(LocaleResolverContext context) {
        Optional<List<Locale.LanguageRange>> localePriorities = getAcceptableLanguages();
        if (!localePriorities.isPresent()) {
            return context.getDefaultLocale();
        }

        List<Locale> resolvedLocales = Locale.filter(localePriorities.get(), context.getSupportedLocales());
        if (resolvedLocales.size() > 0) {
            return resolvedLocales.get(0);
        }

        return context.getDefaultLocale();
    }

    private Optional<List<Locale.LanguageRange>> getAcceptableLanguages() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = ResteasyContext.getContextData(HttpHeaders.class);
        if (httpHeaders != null) {
            List<String> acceptLanguageList = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("Accept-Language");
            if (acceptLanguageList != null && !acceptLanguageList.isEmpty()) {
                return Optional.of(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(acceptLanguageList.get(0)));
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in the [Hibernate Validator guide for Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/validation#validation-and-localization):

> You can configure this behavior by adding the following configuration in your application.properties:
>
> ```
> # The default locale to use
> quarkus.default-locale=fr-FR
> ```
>
> If you are using RESTEasy Reactive, in the context of a JAX-RS endpoint, Hibernate Validator will automatically resolve the optimal locale to use from the Accept-Language HTTP header, provided the supported locales have been properly specified in the application.properties:
>
> ```
> # The list of all the supported locales
> quarkus.locales=en-US,es-ES,fr-FR
> ```

---

If the built-in feature that resolves the locale from the `Accept-Language` HTTP header suits your needs, then you **do not** need a custom locale resolver.

If that built-in feature isn't enough for some reason, you can declare your locale resolver as a CDI bean and it should get automatically picked up:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {
   // ...
}
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you can probably use a [`ValidatorFactoryCustomizer`](https://quarkus.io/guides/validation#configuring-the-validatorfactory):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyValidatorFactoryCustomizer implements ValidatorFactoryCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(BaseHibernateValidatorConfiguration<?> configuration) {
        configuration.localeResolver(customlocaleresolver);
    }
}
```

That last solution will, however, completely override any built-in locale resolver: the `Accept-Language` HTTP header will get completely ignored.

Comment: Hi, I did configured validatorfactorycustomizer like you said. But how should I pass this locale value to my resource bundle - ResourceBundle.getBundle(VALIDATION_MESSAGES, locale)? If I pass hardcoded value to locale, I'm getting the respective language message. But how should I make this dynamic? I tried to debug, but the pointer is not going inside localresolver. Can you please let me know, if I'm missing something

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Please edit your question to show your code, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm able to debug now and found that resteasycontext.getcontextdatamap is returning null for the below custom locale resolver. Could you please let me know how to get header value in the resolver.

Comment: `public class ResteasyContextLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolve(LocaleResolverContext context) {
        Optional<List<LanguageRange>> localePriorities = getAcceptableLanguages();
        if (!localePriorities.isPresent()) {
            return context.getDefaultLocale();
        }

        List<Locale> resolvedLocales = Locale.filter(localePriorities.get(), context.getSupportedLocales());
        if (resolvedLocales.size() > 0) {
            return resolvedLocales.get(0);
        }

        return context.getDefaultLocale();}`

Comment: remaining code - `private Optional<List<Locale.LanguageRange>> getAcceptableLanguages() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = ResteasyContext.getContextData(HttpHeaders.class);
        if (httpHeaders != null) {
            List<String> acceptLanguageList = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("Accept-Language");
            if (acceptLanguageList != null && !acceptLanguageList.isEmpty()) {
                return Optional.of(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(acceptLanguageList.get(0)));
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();}}`

Comment: These are the dependencies I'm using -                                                     
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-rxjava:4.0.0.Beta8'
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:4.0.0.Beta5'
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider'            
     implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'

Comment: @kkamalam Frankly, if you just want to comply with `Accept-Language` headers, don't write your own resolver. That feature is built-in. Just set the accepted locales and default locale as I explained at the beginning of my answer, and Quarkus/RestEasy will take care of the rest. I repeat: DO NOT write your own resolver just for this.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the custom resolver and defined the list of locales in yml file and it worked!